# Haskell - C stack overflow

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I've just been introduced to Haskell, so I'm not very practiced at how to code in the language, and hence, sorry if this is a duplicate, however I do not understand the other code written in the language.

I am trying to write an algorithm that will take the sum of the positive even integers not exceeding the value given. I have attempted to write the code however I have been getting the C stack overflow error.

Here is my code:

```
sumint :: Int -> Int
sumint x
  | x==0 = 0  
  | x==1 = 1
  | (x `mod` 2 == 0) && (x >= 2) = x + (sumint x-2)
  | (x `mod` 2 /= 0) && (x >= 1) = x + (sumint x-1)
```

Where am I going wrong to get this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Initial Error: Infinite Recursion**

Stepping through your code:

```
sumint :: Int -> Int
```

Hey, a type signature.  You rock.

```
sumint x
  | x==0 = 0
```

A base case, cool.

```
  | x==1 = 1
```

A totally unnecessary case.  OK, sure... except.  1 is not even so why are we including it in the sum?  It should be zero (or removed completely).

```
  | (x `mod` 2 == 0) && (x >= 2) = x + (sumint x-2)
```

The meat of the issue is here.  1. X is even - great.  2. X is positive, yep. The  result is `x + (sumint x) - 2`  No!

- Error 1: Notice function application binds tigher than operators so this should be `x + sumint (x-2)`.

This is the reason for your stack overflow.  `sumint 2 == 2 + (sumint 2) - 2 + (sumint 2) -2 + (sumint 2) -2 + ...`, yay infinite recursion.

```
  | (x `mod` 2 /= 0) && (x >= 1) = x + (sumint x-1)
```

Another case... odds... positive... but why are we adding in x?  You want to add evens, not odds.  So fixing the above issue at the same time we get:

- Error 2: If you determine `x` is odd, don't add in `x`.  Just use `sumint (x-1)`.

Then you are out of cases. What happens if x is not positive?  You need (another) case.

```
| otherwise = 0
```

**Next Issue: No Accumulation**

The problem now is you are building up a large thunk (unevaluated computation) instead of operating in constant space by accumulating the result as you progress.  Notice if we expand your computation for, say, 6 we get:

```
sumint 6 = 6 + sumint (6-2) 
      = 6 + 4 + sumint (4-2)
      = 6 + 4 + 2 + sumint (2-2)
      = 6 + 4 + 2 + 0
```

You really don't want to keep all those additions separate, it would be good to pass in an accumulator such as:

```
sumint x = go x 0
 where
  go n accumulator
         | n <= 0    = accumulator
         | odd n     = go (n-1) accumulator
         | otherwise = go (n-2) (accumulator + n)
```

Side note: Other stackoverflow citizens might mention making the accumulator strict, which is good form.  I don't want to distract the current asker with that discussion here.  Notice using optimization, `-O2`, does suffice.

**Idiomatic Solutions**

All the above solutions are rather verbose.  The general operation, iterating over a list with a function and accumulator, is a type of `fold`.  Fold's are one of the many highly optimized structure traversals common in functional programming.  In this case a "strict left fold" is the typical candidate (from `Data.List`).  That is `foldl'`' the prime (`'`) by convention means it is strict  while the `l` means left.

```
sumint n = foldl' (+) 0 [val | val <- [0..n], even val]
```

Here we folded over the list to get our sum.  To create the list of interest we used list comprehension - first enumerating the values from `0..n` and skipping any value that does not meet the predicate `even`.

We can further clean this up and improve it by using the `sum` function and list comprehension that steps by 2, thus giving us only the evens you desire:

```
sumint n = sum [0,2..n]
```

Comment: Tiny detail: `go` should be replaced with `(+)` in the definition of `sumint` that uses `foldl'`. I would make this edit but the change is fewer than 6 characters.

Answer (score 10):

Its an operator precedence problem. In Haskell, function application has the highest possible precedence. Thus when you write `sumint x - 2`, even though you are interpreting it as `sumint (x-2)`, Haskell is interpreting it as `(sumint x) - 2`. Thus -- you are trying to define `sumint x` directly in terms of `sumint x` -- which just piles up recursive function calls until the stack overflows. You need to add explicit parentheses if you want the subtraction evaluated before the function application.